# Error Asp.net Membership Provider when adding user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

The error message below i get when I"m trying to create a new user in a project management system we use for a client. I type in all the corresponding information then when I click create it throws this error.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CallWebAdminMembershipProviderHelperMethodOutParams(String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What causes this error is the hard drive where all databases are being stored is full. Even if there is 1kb left it will post the error. To fix, install a much larger hard drive, or clear any unnecessary files from the hard drive and make free space. the server error or asp.net error you may see from this is the 9002 error. When the hard drive is full the databases log file cannot be written too, which when anything is done to the database, inserting, updating, etc. it is written to the log file. When there is no space left the log file cannot expand therefore throwing an error. I appreciate your help chriskent. By the way if anyone is wondering we had no room left literally not even 1kb to spare, our free space was 0kb. Hope this helps.

Comment: Gah, I hate that sort of thing.

Comment: also truncating the databases log file will fix this problem we had a 7mb database with a 135gb log file that was never truncated like it was suppose too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a machine key element in your web.config?  Ensure this is specifically set (Not autogenerate).  Check this thread for more information:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1213872.aspx

Comment: actually i found the answer the 1tb drive we have that stores all of our databases is full.

Comment: it has no room to increase the log file so it is throwing up an error because if it cannot write to the log file then no access is granted.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: No problem I'm posting detailed information about my fix in my own answer below